# How to get invoice for the Google BigQuery project

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I used Google Bigquery for a month and was billed $800. Since the amount was way high I disabled the billing immediately. However now I need the invoice for the amount charged. If I enable billing back, it gets associated to a new account. For contacting customer support I need billing id which I don't have.

Please let me know, how can I get invoice for this project.

Comment: What info you have about your old account? Please leave a way to contact you.

Comment: I have emailId, cc number etc. You may contact me at bhaktavatsalshukla@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had a similar situation, and I opened a ticket with the wrong billing ID. As long as you have a project ID and you can prove you own the project, they can find the invoice and send it back to you :).

Comment: I did the same and got the invoice. Thanks a lot :)